# Script for restart Tomcat when Out of Memory

Tags: tomcat, out-of-memory, restart

I'm working on script for auto restart tomcat when OOM occured
I put this arguement :
`XX:OnOutOfMemoryError='myscript.sh'`

But when the script restart tomcat it's fails because the stocket is still open while I killed the tomcat PID

So I tried to launch a script from myscript.sh but this new script (OOM.sh) is still open by the stocket so that change nothing.

How I can proceed ?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps your script needs to wait a bit instead of immediately trying to re-launch Tomcat.

Instead of writing your script like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
export CATALINA_HOME=...
export CATALINA_BASE=...
$CATALINA_HOME/bin/catalina.sh start
```

Do it like this instead:

```
#!/bin/sh
export CATALINA_HOME=...
export CATALINA_BASE=...
export CATALINA_PID_FILE=...
export PID=$(cat $CATALINA_PID_FILE)
while [ "1" == "$(kill -0 $PID)" ]; do
    sleep 1
done
$CATALINA_HOME/bin/catalina.sh start
```

This will sleep until Tomcat has shut down. You could add a timeout tht would `kill -9` the process after waiting some amount of time for Tomcat to shut down cleanly... maybe something like 10 seconds.

Comment: thank you for reply. the problem is still here, when the script is launched, he got the same file descriptor and the stocket is still open


when i start tomcat
 
Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 5007

java    7411 root    4u  IPv4  43872      0t0  TCP *:5007 (LISTEN)
OOM.sh  7447 root    4u  IPv4  43872      0t0  TCP *:5007 (LISTEN)

Comment: That comment is unreadable. Try adding some debugging to the script to see what is happening.